# Format UTC Time To Local Time

Tags: datetime, c#, string

When you have a `string` that is formatted in UTC Time, how can I format it to a `DateTime` but local time?

For example, if I have the below code, it improperly formats my code (meaning incorrect time)

```
string dateformatted = "2017-01-10T11:13:00-07:00"
DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(dateformatted));
```

However, the output from this is

```
01/10/2017 1:13:00 PM
```

Which is 2 hours ahead of the actual time of 11:13:00.  How can I convert the string to the proper timezone time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According MSDN [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Parse3_Example):

> Return value Type: DateTime
>
> An object that is equivalent to the date and time contained in s.
>   Generally, the Parse method returns a DateTime object whose Kind
>   property is **DateTimeKind.Unspecified**. However, the Parse method
>   may also perform time zone conversion and set the value of the Kind
>   property differently,depending on the values of the s and styles
>   parameters:

If:

```
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
    |                                             If                                            |                         Time zone conversion                        |    Kind property   |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
    | s contains time zone information.                                                         | The date and time is converted to the time in the local time zone.  | DateTimeKind.Local |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
    | s contains time zone information, and styles includes the AdjustToUniversalflag.          | The date and time is converted to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). | DateTimeKind.Utc   |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
    | s contains the Z or GMT time zone designator, and styles includes the RoundtripKind flag. | The date and time are interpreted as UTC.                           | DateTimeKind.Utc   |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

You should add timezone.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the [Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx) overload of the `Parse` method. The third parameter, `DateTimeStyles`, will allow for force or prohibit conversion between local and UTC times. [Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx) include: `AdjustToUniversal`, `AssumeLocal`, and `AssumeUniversal` (among others).